# C3.js plotting xy chart, line not getting connected properly between points

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, c3.js

Issue with C3.js plotting xy chart. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

```
var T = [];
var F = [];
var n = [];

T.push('T');
F.push('F');

d3.csv("/abc.csv", function(d) {
            {
                True_SJs.push(d[" T"]);
                False_SJs.push(d[" F"]);

            },
            function(error, rows) {
                var chart = c3.generate({
                    bindto: '#roc',
                    data: {
                        x: 'F',
                        columns: [
                            F,
                            T
                        ],
                        order: 'asc',
                        selection: {
                            grouped: true
                        }
                    },
                    zoom: {
                        enabled: true,
                        rescale: true,
                        extent: [1, 10]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        format: {
                            title: function(x) {
                                return 'F' + x;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    grid: {
                        x: {
                            show: true
                        },
                        y: {
                            show: true
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Expected output should be line starting from top of point at 4 and connect next point.
Here is the link of example http://c3js.org/samples/simple_xy.html

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be complete (for e.g. the 2nd parameter to d3.csv has unmatched brackets, there's not definition for True_SJs.... Also you might want to post the contents of the csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your data has repeating x values and corresponding y values are go up and then down. Something like

```
 F => ['F', .... 4, 4, 4, ...];
 T => ['T', .... 21, 23, 22, ...];
```

If you want the line to be continuous you can sort the T values when the F (X) values are equal. Something like

```
// construct an array of arrays - each element contains the T values for an F value
var groupedT = [];
T.forEach(function (e, i) {
    // skip element 0 (the label)
    if (i) {
        groupedT[T[i]] = groupedT[T[i]] || [];
        groupedT[T[i]].push(e);
    }
})
// flattening array of arrays
T = groupedT.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a.concat(b.sort());
}, ['T']);
```

before you generate your chart will get you what you need.